# Removing an array from a PHP JSON object

Tags: php, arrays, json

So a bit of background information is I'm creating a web app and I have 50~ arrays that I'm currently using what I get from an API, I've created a script to find the arrays that I don't need lets call them "bad arrays" but the problem is I'm unsure how I can filter these arrays out with the method I'm using to search through them

I'm searching through them with this script

```
$tagItems = [];
foreach($tags['items'] as $item) {
    if (!$item['snippet']['tags'] || !is_array($item['snippet']['tags'])) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach($item['snippet']['tags'] as $tag) {
        $tag = strtolower($tag);
        if (!isset($tagItems[$tag])) {
            $tagItems[$tag] = 0;
        }
        $tagItems[$tag]++;
    }
}
```

But let's say I didn't want it to include the 8th array and the 15th array

```
$tags['items'][8]['snippet']['tags'];
$tags['items'][15]['snippet']['tags'];
```

I want these to be removed from the original `$tags` array. How can i achieve this?

EDIT: This needs to be dynamic. I do not know if there are going to be 45/50 arrays that will need removing or just 2/50. the array that needs removing can be reffered to as `$index`

I have a script which determines what array(s) need to be removed

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 50) {
    $x = 0;
    while ($x <= 50) {
        if ($tags['items'][$i]['snippet']['channelId'] == $tags['items'][$x]['snippet']['channelId']) {
            if ($x < $i) {
                break;
            } else {
                echo $x.", ";
                break;
            }
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I'm going to edit this a little more to provide some extra information that may be useful. My overall goal is to use the YouTube API to remove all but the first array of tags where the channel id appears multiple times. I'm using a script which finds all the array numbers that **dont** need to be removed an URL.

Comment: I have a script which detects what arrays need to be removed - I'll add it on my original post now

Comment: If it's 8/15 today and 2/50 tomorrow then what the heck is the criteria for knowing this? Is it the relative distance of the sun compared to Google's stock price on a winter day when we only receive 1.235 inches of snow at Central Park in NYC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the array key

```
$tagItems = [];
$toRemove = array(8,15);
foreach($tags['items'] as $key => $item) {
    if(in_array($key,$toRemove)){
        continue;
    }
    if (!$item['snippet']['tags'] || !is_array($item['snippet']['tags'])) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach($item['snippet']['tags'] as $tag) {
        $tag = strtolower($tag);
        if (!isset($tagItems[$tag])) {
            $tagItems[$tag] = 0;
        }
        $tagItems[$tag]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't include this in my original question and I will edit it now as I didn't make myself very clear. How could I do this dynamically, I don't know if it's going to be array 8 or array 15, maybe it's only two arrays, maybe it's 30 arrays that need removing,

Comment: Just a small tidbit, you could combine both `if(){}`s which result in calling `continue` into a single `if(){}` but overall your answer seems correct.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did it like this so it was easier to see what i did, but yes it can be added together ofcourse.

Comment: I've done some testing and it doesn't work, I'm not sure why it doesn't, but it doesn't work - I set toRemove to `$toRemove = array(8,12,15,17,18,21,28,29,33,42);` but these arrays are not being removed, there are also no errors being given - Adding to this i'm unsure what the $key variable is for

Comment: This answer isn't actually removing any entries from `$tags`, it simply isn't performing the additional logic on these entries. That corresponds to the request of "how can I stop the foreach from "foreaching" this piece of data", but not the following request of "is there any way I can just delete it so it doesn't exist" (the two parts of the request kind of contradict each other)

Comment: @PatrickQ surely if the array is removed (non-existent) then it can't be foreached because it just isn't there  I just assume either one would work

Comment: It all depends on what your ultimate goal is. This is why you need to be specific in your questions. If you specifically want it removed from the initial `$tags` array, then you should say so.

Comment: Yes, Patrick, I want it removed from my initial `$tags` array. I'll update the question so it's more thorough, I've also added more information about my overall goal is

Comment: @ConorReidd Add unset($tags['items'][$key]); above the first continue, then it will also remove the entry from $tags.

Comment: @conorReidd Some more explanation: ..$key => $item grabs not only the value, but also the key of the array. For example, when you have $array[3] = 'something', 'something' is the value and 3 is the key. Use print_r($tags) or print_r($tags['items']) to see the keys and values of the array.